# UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean already registered

Tags: oracle, jboss, connection-pooling

I have two web applications.
Both of yhem use **oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPool**.
When I deploy these applications on JBoss I get following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: MBean exception occurred while registering or unregistering the MBean
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:541)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.throwSQLException(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:588)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.startPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:277)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:647)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:614)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:608)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.afterPropertiesSet(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:163)
...  
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: MBean exception occurred while registering or unregistering the MBean
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:541)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.throwSQLException(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:588)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.startPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:248)
    ... 212 more
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: MBean exception occurred while registering or unregistering the MBean
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:421)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:389)
    at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.java:148)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.startPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:243)
    ... 212 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: oracle.ucp.admin:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean already registered.
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.java:135)
    ... 213 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: oracle.ucp.admin:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean already registered.
    at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.add(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:756)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:233)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:140)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl$3.run(MBeanServerImpl.java:1431)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1426)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:376)
    at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl$2.run(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.java:141)
    ... 215 more
```

Definition of data source bean:

```
<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory" factory-method="getPoolDataSource">
    <!-- hard coded properties -->
    <property name="connectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="validateConnectionOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="connectionPoolName" value="ORACLE_CONNECTION_POOL" />
...
</bean>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I am trying to deploy two wars on Tomcat and have the same problem. If I copy the ojdbc6.jar and ucp.jar files into the Tomcat/lib directory AND remove them from my wars then I am able to successfully load both apps. Both steps are necessary. However, I don't find that an acceptable solution and am still looking for an easier/better way of handling this. I am using Spring to configure my datasource as well and don't see a way to change the name: oracle.ucp.admin:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean. I've seen solutions for if you are doing this by hand, but not from within a Spring context

Answer (score 3):

Both pools try to register with JMX under the same name ("oracle.ucp.admin:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBean").

If you [turn off](http://ivaylodivanov.blogspot.com/2010/05/connection-pooling-with-oracle-ucp.html) their JMX capabilities, things should work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to blog is broken :(

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a way to do it without the dms.jar

I added this spring bean:

bean id="OracleJMXDisabler" class="yourpackagename.OracleJMXDisabler" init-method="init"

The class looks like this:

```
public class OracleJMXDisabler
{
    public void init() throws UniversalConnectionPoolException
    {
        UniversalConnectionPoolManager manager = UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager();
        manager.setJmxEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

In my datasource beans I added depends-on=”OracleJMXDisabler” so that it would get initialized first. This works because the UniversalConectionPoolManager is a singleton and there is only one instance of it per application context.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to not deploy the jdbc driver (ojdbc6.jar) as part of your web-apps. Instead provide the jdbc only once as part of the JBoss jvm classpath, placing the driver jar into `<JBOSS_HOME>/server/default/lib`

Comment: I do not deploy jdbc driver as part of web applications.
I put both ojdbc5.jar and ucp.jar to $JBOSS_HOME/server/web/lib. But it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this property in your bean
    
if you set pool name it takes same name throws already exist's error